# C++ Modern usage for sigpause in cross-platform environment?

Tags: c++, variables, signals, posix

I am doing some reverse engineering atm, and the application in terms that I am dealing with is using old POSIX threading system, and in this case it is using the following code (made for Linux):

```cpp
while ( GameRunning() )
  {
    sigblock(512);
    for ( i = SigUsr1Counter; !SigUsr1Counter && !SigAlarmCounter; i = SigUsr1Counter )
      __sigpause(0, 0);
    if ( i > 0 )
    {
      SigUsr1Counter = 0;
      ReceiveData();
    }
    v2 = SigAlarmCounter;
    if ( SigAlarmCounter > 0 )
    {
      SigAlarmCounter = 0;
      AdvanceGame(Beat * v2);
    }
  }
```

The function calls such as __sigpause and sigblock, I suppose this is somekind of pause while waiting for signal system, however, I've no clue how to adapt this to modern C++ and to make it work under Windows as well.

I've read about conditional_variable, but I do not believe it will do the job? Any insights are welcome! Sorry if this has been asked before, kind of learning!

I tried these, signalCount is increased on different threads, but unsure if this is the correct approach.

```cpp
int signalCount = 0;
while (signalCount == 0) {
   sleep(50);
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that conditional variables will not do the job? They are actually capable of sleeping the threads and waking/notifying the ones that are sleeping. Seems applicable here.

Comment: Can you describe the wider problem more. Are these signals being used between threads or between processes?

Comment: They are used between threads. I really have no idea how to make use of conditionals for this exact behavior.